# Migrate datat MongoDB in liquibase

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, liquibase

I have in mongo 2 collections that look something like this:

collection1:

```
{
"id": "someId",
"name": "someName"
}
```

colleciton2:

```
{
"_id": "id",
"objectOfTypeCollection1": [{
    "id": "someId2",
    "name": "someName2"
    }]
}
```

After the migration I need to have:
collection1:

```
{
"id": "someId",
"name": someName
},
{
"id": "someId2",
"name": "someName2"
}
```

This is easly done with some javascript code, but I need to have this migration in Liquibase, which means using runCommand. As of now I am unaware of a way to have a find command inside the update command in order to manage to move the data from collection2.objectOfTypeCollection1 into collection1.

To put it simple, can you use JS in runCommand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`$merge`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/)

```
db.runCommand( {
   aggregate: db.collection2.getName(),
   pipeline: [ 
   {  $unwind: "$objectOfTypeCollection1" },
   {
      $merge: {
         into: db.collection1.getName()
      }
   } 
   ],
   cursor: {}
} )
```